# Why does community bot keep reviving over decade old topics?

Tags: support, community

Example: [Folders visible on flash drive, but no files](https://superuser.com/questions/515698/folders-visible-on-flash-drive-but-no-files)

Over decade old. I'm sure OP doesn't care anymore, will not answer anymore etc.. what's the use of the community bot 'modifying' the topic?

Comment: See [Is the community bot ruining the community by bumping old posts? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327150/is-the-community-bot-ruining-the-community-by-bumping-old-posts)

Comment: And [Community bot raking up abandoned questions - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242544/community-bot-raking-up-abandoned-questions)

Comment: Right, thank you. As a follow-up question, it would be perfectly acceptable for me to answer it then, correct?

Comment: If you wish....

Comment: Well I am trying to determine if it's allowed and considered useful. I *wish* to contribute. I just see a question I think I have a useful answer to, notice it's old, yet 'bumped' for *some* reason.

Comment: It's odd when it's something you answered yourself years ago, then over a couple of days you get seemingly random upvotes.. took me ages to figure out how it was happening, because I never look at the questions by 'Active' only ever by 'Newest'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The community bot keeps reviving over decade old topics because sometimes the question has either no answers or doesn't have answer that was accepted by the original poster.

You can safely answer old questions. If you have a good answer, it will get upvoted. And if the user who posed the answer is still active, they might check it off as the answer. That is the whole reason old posts get recycled: To get new eyeballs looking at them.

And the other side to this is if the question simply bad, it gets a new set of eyes on it to potentially edit it and clean it up or just flag it to be closed and deleted. Remember, this is a community and bringing up old questions actually helps with the whole collaborative moderation aspect of this place.